# Error: main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `MyThing::MyThing ()

Tags: c++, reference, undefined

I have slimmed down everything to barebones and still getting the same errors. I now have just my constructor and still got an error: main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `MyThing::MyThing
()'

Any help would be much appreciated. My code:

**MyThing.h**

```
#ifndef MYTHING_H
#define MYTHING_H
class MyThing
{
  public:
    MyThing();
};
#endif
```

**MyThing.cpp**

```
#include "MyThing.h"
using namespace std;         
    
MyThing::MyThing(){}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyThing.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    MyThing lt;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Include your build command(s) [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71609807/edit).

Comment: You probably did not compile `MyThing.cpp` If you are using VSCode that is understandable since the default behavior of the c++ support in the IDE is to build only the active file. The documentation explains what change to make to the tasks.json to build more than 1 source  file.

Comment: I like how you never forget to write `using namespace std;`

Comment: @drescherjm you were spot on, I am using VS Code and did need to adjust my launch.json and tasks.json. Many thanks for all. Apologies for coming back after so long, really did not expect such a prompt response from all.